# Google Cloud App Engine - Eclipse shows "runtime: java 11" in app.yaml is not Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Trying to deploy an external jar file to Google Cloud App Engine via Eclipse (via Google Cloud Tools plugin).

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: java11
entrypoint: 'java -jar cord.jar'
```

On Eclipse, shows `"runtime: java 1" in app.yaml is not "java"`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you wanted to use Java 11 on GAE Flex, which wasn't supported when you wrote this question. However, that has changed.

Java 11 and 17 are [now available in Google App Engine Flex](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/runtime#newversions) in preview.

Simply add the following to the `runtime_config:` of your `app.yaml`.

```
runtime_config:
    operating_system: "ubuntu18"
    runtime_version: "11"
```

Answer (score 0):

Runtime `java11` is not a supported runtime in App Engine Flexible. Instead you should use `runtime: java`

Here you can see a sample [java app.yaml](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/flexible/helloworld/src/main/appengine/app.yaml) and the [Java documentation for flex](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java)

You can use java11 if you deploy your application in [Standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/runtime) which supports Java 11

If you are deploying to App engine standard you can select in the menu which version you want to deploy

[image]

Comment: Oh, so the plugin gets to only "Flex"? Can i change it to use "Standard" ? When i tried to create a new Standard Application, it only has "Java 8" as Java version

Comment: Well, I dont have eclipse installed right now but In the [Public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/creating-new-webapp) is described the process to deploy and choose the Java version. If in the dropdown menu is only available Java 8 then you can always try to manually deploy to App Engine